# Formbuilder in Wordpress - field entries disappear when trying to input data

Tags: wordpress, formbuilder

I've built a form in formbuilder - only Individual data, some core fields, some custom fields.

WordPress 6.2.2 and CiviCRM 5.57.1 currently

When I try to view the form, it looks OK and I can select an entry for 'Existing Contact', but then any other information disappears as soon as I type or select an option. I can see it for perhaps a second and then it disappears.

The console has some angular errors:[image: Console errors]

I've tried a couple of options, e.g. disabling the Asset Caching and forcing SSL, but that's not helped. No other issues with the site, e.g. Status Page is fine, dashboard is fine, etc.

ETA: The network tab shows the two requests constantly loading for the existing contact/autofill:

[image]

I don't have an settings in the form in the Autofill option.

Any help will be gratefully received

Comment: If you look at the network tab in your browser tools you may find a request that is failing that will give you more info.

Comment: Thank you @Aidan, details now added

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm, I updated the site yesterday to 5.60 and the error is now fixed!

Bit obvious to try that first...